# Перенос значений из одного ключа в другой python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть словарь, нужно что-бы 1 значение из 1 ключа переместилось в другой по значению, чтобы в коде можно было указать название значения и ключ в которое он переместиться

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
```

вот так

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': ['11-2']
```

или так

```
directories = {
    '1': ['11-2'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': ['2207 876234']
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
directories['3'].append(directories['1'].pop())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
directories['3'], directories['1'] = [directories['1'][1]], [directories['1'][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_docs(numbers, direct, shelf):
    if shelf not in direct :
        return print("Полки стаким номером не существует")
    for key, value in direct.items():
        if numbers in value:
            value.remove(numbers)
            direct[shelf].append(numbers)
            return print(f"Документ успешно перемещён на {shelf} полку")
    return print("Документа с таким номером не найдено")

move_docs(11-2, directories, 3)
```

Будет выглядеть так:

```
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': ['11-2']
```